# JS - Return number of active days left of PIN-code based on end date

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm trying to convert an Excel formula to JS to use in a website. I want to use something similar to IF TODAY, for example `=IF(B2;B2-TODAY();" ")` in a table and have it calculate each row to see if a PIN-code is active or if it has expired based on an end date and todays date.

I would also like the column (not entire row) to change background color to green if active and red if expired. See attached image that shows what the table looks like in Excel. In the picture TODAY is 2020-02-29 (YYYY-MM-DD).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the day difference like so:

```js
function calculateActive(endDate) {
  var now = new Date();
  endDate = new Date(endDate)
  
  if(endDate > now) {
   return Math.round(Math.abs((now) - (endDate))/8.64e7);
  } else {
   return (Math.round(Math.abs((now) - (endDate))/8.64e7))*-1;
  }
}

var result = calculateActive("2020-02-15")

if(result > 0) {
 document.getElementById("a").style.color = `green`
} else {
 document.getElementById("a").style.color = `red`
}

document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = result
```

```html
<p>
Days Since: 
</p>
<span id="a"></span>
```

Comment: Could you explain how I would implement this in a table like my attached picture? `var result = calculateActive("2020-02-15")` sets a defined date instead of using todays date as far as I can tell.

Comment: You can pass in any date you want. Thats just an example. To implement this you can just iterate over your table and run the function for each date